# Check if 2 coordinates are in the same city

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-api-3

Basically, I have 2 LatLong values 1 for the user that keeps updating according to his current location and 1 stored on the database. How can I check if these 2 coordinates are in the same city or state.
Note: I used the google maps API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=33.26944346171845,%2035.20463784635442&sensor=true&key=KEY for both coordinates and compared strings(administrative_area_level_2) to check if the user is in the same city or not. Is there a better way to do it in Flutter?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is quite reasonable. If you don't want to use API, you can calculate the distance between two coordinates with the below method. Using this, you can assume that those below a certain distance are in the same city or state.

```js
const convertToRadian = x => x * Math.PI / 180;

function getDistanceBetween(lat1, lat2, lng1, lng2) {
    const R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
    const dLat = convertToRadian(lat2 - lat1);
    const dLong = convertToRadian(lng2 - lng1);
    const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(convertToRadian(lat1)) * Math.cos(convertToRadian(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
    const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return R * c; // returns the distance in meter
}
```

Comment: I see thank you @Salih Can. It's not that I don't want to use the google maps API, I don't like the idea of comparing strings to know if the user is in the same city or not. Your solution solves that issue but I still can't figure out a way to make it accurate.